# bundle is locked to rest_client (1.8.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, rest-client

> Your bundle is locked to rest_client (1.8.3), but that version could
>   not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you
>   haven't changed sources, that means the author of rest_client (1.8.3)
>   has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different
>   version of rest_client (1.8.3) that hasn't been removed in order to
>   install.

Comment: try `bundle update` or remove the Gemfile.lock and do `bundle install`.

Comment: I tried everything. nothing happens. 

when i try to update it shows:
Could not find gem 'rest_client' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or in gems cached in vendor/cache.

When i try to install this gem this error shown: 
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rest_client' (= 1.8.3) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rest-client

I remove gemfile.lock and use bundle install same error appear: 
Could not find gem 'rest_client' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or in gems cached in vendor/cache.

Comment: [`gem install rest-client`](https://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client).

Comment: not working. I just remove all of ruby version. re install ruby. remove project directory again clone this. but result is same.

Comment: How does your `Gemfile` look like? Is there a line like `gem 'rest_client'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rest_client` is deprecated. That's why your bundler couldn't find it in any source. Either you have to install it from git or you have to use `rest-client` which is in the source (RubyGems.org).
But your Gemfile.lock file has `rest_client` locked. Follow these steps:

1. Remove your `Gemfile.lock` file.
2. Remove `rest_client` from your `Gemfile`.
3. Add `gem 'rest-client'` to your `Gemfile`.
4. `bundle install`.

Your problem is solved hopefully.